Bin Packing Optimization (Schedule Generation)
I am trying to generate a schedule.
Students pick a number of subjects (normally 3), then I need to place those students in a subject they choose in each timeslot (period).
The number of timeslots is determined by the number of subjects chosen (again normally 3).
There are say 75 subject choices to choose from.
I can have as many subjects classes (sessions) as needed but they need to be spread out evenly across the timeslots (periods), that way less teachers would be required for each subject.
Students can't have two classes in the same period.
Class size is a concern but not something I forced in my algorithm, yet.  I just create a number sessions (classes) based on how many students picked that subject. And try to fill the sessions evenly.
The algorithm I came up with below works fairly well on a set of randomized data but there's still ~80 or so Student/Subject that could not be placed.
Any suggestions or pointers to help optimize this would be very much appreciated.
If I missed any information I'm happy to help clarify.
Career = Subject
Class = Session
Timeslot = Period

Initialization stuff:
var surveys = await _context.Surveys
    .Include(s => s.Student)
    .Include(s => s.PrimaryCareers)
    .Include(s => s.SecondaryCareers)
    .Where(s => s.Student.EventId == eventId).ToListAsync();

var periodCount = surveys.First().PrimaryCareers.Count;

// Dictionary to count the number of times each primary career is selected
var primaryCareerCounts = surveys
    .SelectMany(s => s.PrimaryCareers)
    .GroupBy(c => c)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());

// Sort the surveys list based on primary career popularity, then gender, then grade
var sortedSurveys = surveys
    .OrderBy(s => s.PrimaryCareers.Max(c => primaryCareerCounts.TryGetValue(c, out int value) ? value : 0))
    .ThenBy(s => s.Student.Gender)
    .ThenByDescending(s => s.Student.Grade)
    .ToList();

var allSessions = new List<Session>();

// Initialize Sessions
foreach(var count in primaryCareerCounts)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < Math.Ceiling((double)count.Value / stdRoomSize); i++)
    {
        allSessions.Add(new Session {
            Subject = count.Key,
            EventId = eventId
        });
    }
}

// Initialize Periods
var periods = new List<List<Session>>();
for (int i = 0; i < periodCount; i++)
{
    var sessionList = new List<Session>();
    periods.Add(sessionList);
}

// Initialize Session population map
var sessionPopulation = new Dictionary<Session, int>();
foreach(var session in allSessions)
{
    sessionPopulation[session] = 0;
}

List<Session> FindSessionsForCareerSorted(Career career)
{
    return sessionPopulation
        .Where(kvp => kvp.Key.Subject == career)
        .OrderBy(kvp => kvp.Value)
        .Select(kvp => kvp.Key)
        .ToList();
}

// Initialize Conflict Map
var conflictMap = new Dictionary<int, HashSet<Student>>();
for (int i = 0; i < periods.Count; i++)
{
    conflictMap[i] = new HashSet<Student>();
}

// Initialize Unplaced Students
var unplacedStudents = new List<UnplacedStudentDto>();`

First attempt to place students:
// Assign Students
foreach(Survey survey in sortedSurveys)
{
    foreach(Career pCareer in survey.PrimaryCareers)
    {
        bool isAdded = false;

        // Find session for that career with least students
        var sessions = FindSessionsForCareerSorted(pCareer);
        foreach(Session session in sessions)
        {
            // If period already assigned, check if student already has session in that period
            // Else, Find periods with least sessions and no session with current session's career subject
            if (session.Period == 0) {
                // Session not assigned period, find a period
                var careerSubjectCounts = periods
                    .Select(period => period.Count(s => s.Subject == session.Subject))
                    .ToList();

                // Determine the minimum count of sessions for the specified career subject
                int minCount = careerSubjectCounts.Min();

                // Return only those with the minimum count of sessions of that subject
                var availablePeriods = periods
                    .Select((period, index) => new { Period = period, Index = index })
                    .Where(x => careerSubjectCounts[x.Index] == minCount)
                    .OrderBy(x => x.Period.Count)
                    .ToList();
                
                foreach(var availPeriod in availablePeriods)
                {
                    int periodIndex = availPeriod.Index;
                    var periodSessions = availPeriod.Period;

                    // Check for conflict
                    bool hasConflict = conflictMap[periodIndex].Contains(survey.Student);

                    if (!hasConflict) {
                        // Add Student to session
                        session.AddStudent(survey.Student);
                        // Add Session to period
                        session.Period = periodIndex + 1;
                        periods[periodIndex].Add(session);
                        // Add Student to conflict map
                        conflictMap[periodIndex].Add(survey.Student);
                        // Increment session population
                        sessionPopulation[session]++;

                        isAdded = true;

                        break;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                // Session already has period
                bool hasConflict = conflictMap[session.Period - 1].Contains(survey.Student);

                if (!hasConflict) {
                    //Add Student to session
                    session.AddStudent(survey.Student);
                    //Add Student to conflict map
                    conflictMap[session.Period - 1].Add(survey.Student);
                    //Increment session population
                    sessionPopulation[session]++;

                    isAdded = true;

                    break;
                }
            }
            if (isAdded) break;
        }


        // If Conflict, add Student, Conflicting PrimaryCareer
        if (!isAdded) {
            unplacedStudents.Add(new UnplacedStudentDto
                {
                    Student = survey.Student,
                    Career = pCareer
                });
        }
    }
}

Attempting to Resolve Conflicts by moving other classes of same student to a different period
foreach(UnplacedStudentDto unplacedStudentCareer in unplacedStudents)
{
    Student unplacedStudent = unplacedStudentCareer.Student;
    Career unplacedCareer = unplacedStudentCareer.Career;
    bool isAdded = false;

    // Find each period they are enrolled in a session
    var enrolledPeriods = allSessions
        .Where(session => session.Students.Contains(unplacedStudent))
        .Select(session => session.Period - 1)
        .ToList();

    List<Session> enrolledSessions = [];
    for (int index = 0; index < periods.Count; index++)
    {
        Session enrolledSession = periods[index]
            .Where(session => session.Students.Contains(unplacedStudent))
            .FirstOrDefault();

        if (enrolledSession != null) {
            enrolledSessions.Add(enrolledSession);
        }
    }

    // Find enrolledSession that can move to open period
    foreach(Session enrolledSession in enrolledSessions)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < periods.Count; i++)
        {
            // Open Period
            if (!enrolledPeriods.Contains(i)) {
                // Available session
                Session openSession = periods[i]
                    .Where(session => session.Subject == enrolledSession.Subject)
                    .OrderBy(session => session.Students.Count)
                    .FirstOrDefault();

                Session sessionToPlace = periods[enrolledSession.Period - 1]
                    .Where(session => session.Subject == unplacedCareer)
                    .OrderBy(session => session.Students.Count)
                    .FirstOrDefault();

                if (openSession != null && sessionToPlace != null) {
                    // enrolledSession to openSession
                    // sessionToPlace to enrolledSession
                    // Remove student from enrolled Session
                    enrolledSession.RemoveStudent(unplacedStudent.Id);
                    // Remove student from conflict map
                    conflictMap[enrolledSession.Period - 1].Remove(unplacedStudent);
                    // Decrement sessionPopulation
                    sessionPopulation[enrolledSession]--;

                    // Add student to openSession
                    openSession.AddStudent(unplacedStudent);
                    // Add student to conflict map
                    conflictMap[openSession.Period - 1].Add(unplacedStudent);
                    // Increment sessionPopulation
                    sessionPopulation[openSession]++;

                    // Add student to sessionToPlace
                    sessionToPlace.AddStudent(unplacedStudent);
                    // Add student to conflict map
                    conflictMap[sessionToPlace.Period - 1].Add(unplacedStudent);
                    // Increment sessionPopulation
                    sessionPopulation[sessionToPlace]++;

                    // Placed Student
                    placedStudents.Add(unplacedStudentCareer);
                    isAdded = true;
                    break;
                } else if (openSession != null || sessionToPlace != null) {
                    // Check other enrolledSessions for session to place
                    foreach(Session otherEnrolledSession in enrolledSessions.Where(s => s != enrolledSession))
                    {
                        // enrolledSession.period has session for unplaced career
                        // enrolledSession can NOT go in open period
                        
                        // Can otherEnrolledSession go in open period? 
                        // AND can enrolledSession go in otherEnrolledSession.period

                        // sessionToPlace go into entrolledSession.period
                        // entrolledSession go into otherEnrolledSession.period
                        // otherEnrolledSession go into open.period
                        if (sessionToPlace != null && openSession == null) {
                            openSession = periods[i]
                                .Where(session => session.Subject == otherEnrolledSession.Subject)
                                .OrderBy(session => session.Students.Count)
                                .FirstOrDefault();

                            Session enrolledToOtherEnrolled = periods[otherEnrolledSession.Period - 1]
                                .Where(session => session.Subject == enrolledSession.Subject)
                                .OrderBy(session => session.Students.Count)
                                .FirstOrDefault();

                            if (openSession != null && enrolledToOtherEnrolled != null) {
                                // sessionToPlace go into entrolledSession.period
                                // entrolledSession go into otherEnrolledSession.period
                                // otherEnrolledSession go into open.period

                                enrolledSession.RemoveStudent(unplacedStudent.Id);
                                // Remove student from conflict map
                                conflictMap[enrolledSession.Period - 1].Remove(unplacedStudent);
                                // Decrement sessionPopulation
                                sessionPopulation[enrolledSession]--;

                                // Add student to sessionToPlace
                                sessionToPlace.AddStudent(unplacedStudent);
                                // Add student to conflict map
                                conflictMap[sessionToPlace.Period - 1].Add(unplacedStudent);
                                // Increment sessionPopulation
                                sessionPopulation[sessionToPlace]++;

                                //Remove student from otherEnrolledSession
                                otherEnrolledSession.RemoveStudent(unplacedStudent.Id);
                                //Remove student from conflict map
                                conflictMap[otherEnrolledSession.Period - 1].Remove(unplacedStudent);
                                //Decrement sessionPopulation
                                sessionPopulation[otherEnrolledSession]++;

                                //Add entrolledSession to otherEnrolledSession
                                enrolledToOtherEnrolled.AddStudent(unplacedStudent);
                                //Add student to conflict map
                                conflictMap[enrolledToOtherEnrolled.Period - 1].Add(unplacedStudent);
                                //Increment sessionPopulation
                                sessionPopulation[enrolledToOtherEnrolled]++;

                                // Add otherEnrolledSession to openSession
                                openSession.AddStudent(unplacedStudent);
                                // Add student to conflict map
                                conflictMap[openSession.Period - 1].Add(unplacedStudent);
                                // Increment sessionPopulation
                                sessionPopulation[openSession]++;

                                // Placed Student
                                placedStudents.Add(unplacedStudentCareer);
                                isAdded = true;
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                        // enrolledSession can go in open period
                        // sessonToPlace can NOT go in enrolledSession.period

                        // Can otherEnrolledSession go into enrolledSession.period
                        // AND sessionToPlace go in otherEnrolledSession.period?

                        // enrolledSession go into open.period
                        // otherEnrolledSession go into enrolledSession.period
                        // sessionToPlace go into otherEnrolledSession.period
                        if (openSession != null && sessionToPlace == null) {
                            sessionToPlace = periods[otherEnrolledSession.Period - 1]
                                .Where(session => session.Subject == unplacedCareer)
                                .OrderBy(session => session.Students.Count)
                                .FirstOrDefault();

                            Session otherEnrolledToEnrolled = periods[enrolledSession.Period - 1]
                                .Where(session => session.Subject == otherEnrolledSession.Subject)
                                .OrderBy(session => session.Students.Count)
                                .FirstOrDefault();

                            if (sessionToPlace != null && otherEnrolledToEnrolled != null) {
                                // Remove student from enrolled Session
                                enrolledSession.RemoveStudent(unplacedStudent.Id);
                                // Remove student from conflict map
                                conflictMap[enrolledSession.Period - 1].Remove(unplacedStudent);
                                // Decrement sessionPopulation
                                sessionPopulation[enrolledSession]--;

                                // Add student to sessionToPlace
                                sessionToPlace.AddStudent(unplacedStudent);
                                // Add student to conflict map
                                conflictMap[sessionToPlace.Period - 1].Add(unplacedStudent);
                                // Increment sessionPopulation
                                sessionPopulation[sessionToPlace]++;

                                //Remove student from otherEnrolledSession
                                otherEnrolledSession.RemoveStudent(unplacedStudent.Id);
                                //Remove student from conflict map
                                conflictMap[otherEnrolledSession.Period - 1].Remove(unplacedStudent);
                                //Decrement sessionPopulation
                                sessionPopulation[otherEnrolledSession]++;

                                //Add entrolledSession to otherEnrolledSession
                                otherEnrolledToEnrolled.AddStudent(unplacedStudent);
                                //Add student to conflict map
                                conflictMap[otherEnrolledToEnrolled.Period - 1].Add(unplacedStudent);
                                //Increment sessionPopulation
                                sessionPopulation[otherEnrolledToEnrolled]++;

                                // Add student to openSession
                                openSession.AddStudent(unplacedStudent);
                                // Add student to conflict map
                                conflictMap[openSession.Period - 1].Add(unplacedStudent);
                                // Increment sessionPopulation
                                sessionPopulation[openSession]++;

                                // Placed Student
                                placedStudents.Add(unplacedStudentCareer);
                                isAdded = true;
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                        // enrolledSession can NOT go into open.period
                        // sessionToPlace can NOT go into enrolledSession.period

                        // Can sessionToPlace go into otherEnrolledSession.period
                        // Can otherEnrolledSession go into open.period
                        if (openSession == null && sessionToPlace == null) {
                            openSession = periods[i]
                                .Where(session => session.Subject == otherEnrolledSession.Subject)
                                .OrderBy(session => session.Students.Count)
                                .FirstOrDefault();

                            sessionToPlace = periods[otherEnrolledSession.Period - 1]
                                .Where(session => session.Subject == unplacedCareer)
                                .OrderBy(session => session.Students.Count)
                                .FirstOrDefault();
                            
                            if (openSession != null && sessionToPlace != null) {
                                // otherEnrolledSession to openSession
                                // sessionToPlace to otherEnrolledSession
                                otherEnrolledSession.RemoveStudent(unplacedStudent.Id);
                                // Remove student from conflict map
                                conflictMap[otherEnrolledSession.Period - 1].Remove(unplacedStudent);
                                // Decrement sessionPopulation
                                sessionPopulation[otherEnrolledSession]--;

                                // Add student to openSession
                                openSession.AddStudent(unplacedStudent);
                                // Add student to conflict map
                                conflictMap[openSession.Period - 1].Add(unplacedStudent);
                                // Increment sessionPopulation
                                sessionPopulation[openSession]++;

                                // Add student to sessionToPlace
                                sessionToPlace.AddStudent(unplacedStudent);
                                // Add student to conflict map
                                conflictMap[sessionToPlace.Period - 1].Add(unplacedStudent);
                                // Increment sessionPopulation
                                sessionPopulation[sessionToPlace]++;

                                // Placed Student
                                placedStudents.Add(unplacedStudentCareer);
                                isAdded = true;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (isAdded) break;
    }
}


Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
